# Ubuntu touch support for POS machine

Tags: 14.04, touchscreen

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 in my POS (rio). Touch is not working. I am looking for solution to enable my touch screen. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Point of Sale, or the other kind of POS?

Comment: Point of sale. Software developed for my company by others. It works well in windows machine with touch. But I don't get any clue to activate the touchscreen capabily.